# EWS Notifications for Delegated Folders

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I need to subscribe to Free busy information for delegated calendars. We have access to one account. That account has access delegated by a number of other calendars.

How can I subscribe to FreeBusyChanged events for all delegated calendars? 
Is it possible to subscribe to the one account and receive events for all delegated calendars or do I have to subscribe to every delegated calendar separately?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, subscriptions (push, pull, or streaming) select a single calendar.  The subscribe call requires a folderid to subscribe to.